# Can I make a Static variable Volatile in c# in Async-await architecture ?. What are the pros and cons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a network application in Winform c# 6.0. The application using async await architecture. In some places I am accessing static public variables by another classes without creating objects. I want to know if there is any drawback of declaring static variables volatile or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: volatile disables a number of compiler and runtime optimisations, that are beneficial in single-task scenarios. Volatile is also unessesary, as it only helps with multi**threading** and you use threadless multitasking.

Comment: Also the whole idea of sharing data via a static field is a common mistake. Static fields should be used for readonly and constant data only. At worst I would make a class that needs instantiation and assign it to a static field - that bit of change already allows a ton of additional options

Comment: Hi  Christopher, Thanks for reply, do you mean that async await is threadless multitasking.

Comment: Indeed, async...await is threadless multitasking. We always could have done it ourself, but the code for that is very complex and prone to error. Async/Await has the Frameworkand runtime do that job for us.

Comment: Actually I am not sharing data via static field. There are some boolean variables which are used to identify the current state of some operations.

Comment: It makes no difference, current jitters already treat static variables as volatile.  Do avoid assuming that is useful at all to make code thread-safe.

Comment: You get to be the judge of what constitutes a _pro_ or a _con_.  We can tell you _what_ happens, but it's up to you to decide if the behaviour or style is a _drawback_.

Comment: "Actually I am not sharing data via static field. There are some boolean variables which are used to identify the current state of some operations. " So you are sharing the state of the operations via a a bunch of boolean variables, using a static field? Yes, that is sharing data that can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why we use volatile**

Fast memory is expensive. RAM is acceptably fast, but compared to the memory used inside the CPU even it is slow. Modern Multicore CPU's have *layers* internal caching memory, that get faster the closer to a single core you get.

With Multithreading applications it becomes an issue propagating a single change all the way from a L1 cache to L3, and then back upwards into all other L1 caches. So you could run into issues like the L1 chache of some cores having gotten the update, but others still being on a previous value. A race condition on hardware level.

There is also the part where the Compiler, JiT and the Runtime can decide do add and remove temproary variables if it is deemed advantageous for performance. Like pruning 2+ accesses of the same index, to 1 access that copies to a temporary variable. Or cutting a temporary variable out as "underused". So you end up unpredictable stale values all over the place.

VOLTAILE turns all that off. So you will not get **additional** sources of race conditons from the hardware, JiT, runtime or any similar source. You still have all the *normal* danger of race conditons however, so it is not Thread Safety - merely a part of it.

**While you do not need it with async/await**

async/await is designed as a threadless way to implement multitasking. So async/await will not even run into the issues volatile is trying to fix.

For a long time "throwing threads at it" was the most expedient way to get Multitasking done in just about every language. Multi**threading** is only stricly nessesrary with CPU bound works, but it was a quick, dirty and reliable way to get Multtiasking done. The code for doing multiasking in a single thread was verbose, complex and incredibly easy for a human programmer to mess up. async/await has the compiler and runtime take care of the plumbing for you, the same way they deal with memory management for you. With those two (and compatriots in other languages) we can finally stop overeusing multithreading to get multitasking done.

**Avoid static missuse**

static has often been used as a easy way to exchange data. My advise is to only use static from compile (const) and runtime (static readonly) constants.

The closest I ever got to exchange data with it, was using a class that needs instantiation and assigning a instance to a static field. With code being given the instance via a argument, never even needing access to the static field directly.

That way at least I can have multiple instances, exchange implementations and do other stuff that direct access to a static field would never allow.